# Ruby, Socket instance defined outside of class, unable to be used within a class

Tags: ruby, class, sockets

I'm pretty new to ruby, I just started yesterday. I'm trying to have this connect to an irc server, join a channel, print a message, quit, and then close the socket.

```
require 'socket'

# server information
$host = 'irc.m8chat.net'
$port = 6667
$nick = "m8bot"
$channel = "##bottesting"

s = TCPSocket.open($host, $port)

class Irc
   def init
      s.write("NICK #{$nick}")
      s.write("USER #{$nick} 0 * :#{$nick}")
   end

   def quit(msg = $nick)
      s.write("QUIT :#{msg}")
   end

   def join(chan = $channel)
      s.write("JOIN #{chan}")
   end

   def send_msg(msg)
      s.write("SAY #{$channel} :#{msg}")
   end

   def cmd(cmd)
      s.write(cmd)
   end
end

irc = Irc.new

irc.join
irc.send_msg("Hello world")
irc.quit

s.close
```

The problem here is that s can't be used within class Irc. I tried to append $ before every occurrence of s, and while I didn't get anything back, nothing happened either. I feel like I'm missing something pretty simple here.

I'd love some feedback, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `s` is a local variable and you won't be able to use it inside your class unless you pass it in. All your $ variables are global and you should avoid global variables if you can. I can't tell you why `$a` hasn't worked but I would suggest you read [something about dependency injection](http://solnic.eu/2013/12/17/the-world-needs-another-post-about-dependency-injection-in-ruby.html) or [the Ruby variable scope](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Variable_Scope).

I don't know if you do this for educational reasons but there [is help](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/irc_bots) like [cinch](https://github.com/cinchrb/cinch) and even if you don't want to use any of these libraries you can still get an insight of how they work.

Comment: Yes, this is more for practice than anything else. Thank you for your input :)

Comment: @NiaKitty I [rewrote your code](https://gist.github.com/2called-chaos/fa0ff946d763cd773323) a bit to be more ruby like, maybe it can help you. I haven't tested it but I guess it also won't solve your problem with IRC communication. I'm lazy and use cinch :)